# OPENXML, Convert Base64 to Binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

For an import/export process, we put binary data into XML as Base64 encoded strings.  The issue came up when getting the values back out...

We're using OPENXML because performance on 2005/2008 is horrid using [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) - it doesn't scale well at all.  They fixed the performance issue in SQL Server 2012, but for the sake of legacy support (2005+) it's not a realistic option, and MS doesn't appear to want to backport things (assuming even possible).

Here's some [relevant info on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/30/converting-from-base64-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx).

Ideally, I'm looking for a single SQL statement using OPENXML to shred an XML document that contains binary data encoded to Base64, and provide a result set there that data is correctly rendered as binary data.  I have one solution that doesn't use nodes, hoping someone has something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify your column as XML and use `.value` to get the data as `varbinary`.

Something like this.

```sql
declare @XML xml 

set @XML = 
'<root>
  <item>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Col>Um93MQ==</Col>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Col>Um93Mg==</Col>
  </item>
</root>'

declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @xml

select T.ID,
       T.Col.value('.', 'varbinary(max)')
from openxml(@idoc, '/root/item', 2)
with (ID int,
      Col xml) as T

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Or you could make use of CLR (if that is an option for you) something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
    public class CLRTest
    {
        public static byte[] ConvertBase64ToBinary(string str)
        {
            if (str == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx - better than my `CAST(N'').value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column('Col'), 'VARBINARY(MAX)')`